# How can I set a value to a label through a Thread?

Tags: asp.net

This code is giving an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object'.

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _Default obj = new _Default();
        Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(obj.ThreadStart));
        thread.Start();

    }
    public void ThreadStart()
    {
        show();
    }
    private void show()
    {
        lblget.Text = "hi";
    }
```

Comment: What the heck are you trying to achieve? What do you expect should happen with the Page object you create yourself?

Comment: Follow this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to create an instance of _Default.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(show);
        thread.Start();
    }
    private void show()
    {
        lblget.Text = "hi";
    }
```

Read these article - [Use Threads and Build Asynchronous Handlers in Your Server-Side Web Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164128.aspx) and [PageAsyncTask.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx)